# Logwatch httpd - Lot of probes

Tags: logwatch

Recently Logwatch detects much more probes on my server than usual. Here an example of my yesterday logwatch report:

```
--------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------ 

A total of **10415** sites probed the server 
95.138.82.51 
95.138.88.62 
95.138.95.75 
105.100.141.37 
105.100.155.97 
105.100.157.184 
... 
Requests with error response codes 
400 Bad Request 
null: **159539** Time(s) 
... 
--------------------- httpd End ------------------------
```

Is there a way to reduce this spam or detect nature of those annonying bots?

Comment: This has nothing to do with spam, removed that tag. It's just a configuration issue. See for example [Ubuntu Community Wiki: Logwatch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logwatch) and [Customize Logwatch](http://www.stellarcore.net/logwatch/tabs/docs/HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just a little confused to see suddenly over 10k probes per day on my server, whereas usually I can see only 2 or 3 probes per month.